# What should the tag for Walking Dead - Survival Instinct be called?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got a [the-walking-dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead) tag for the 2012 Telltale game, but there's no tag for [The Walking Dead Survival Instinct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead:_Survival_Instinct), a game released by Activision in March 2013.

[walking-dead-survival-instinct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walking-dead-survival-instinct) is just too long, so I was considering [walking-dead-survival](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walking-dead-survival) as I'm about to ask a question about the game, which will entail creating *a* tag.

Any objections to [walking-dead-survival](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walking-dead-survival), or perhaps better ideas on what the tag should be? Given that this is the *first* question about the game on the site, I don't think it's going to be a wildly popular tag to begin with. I'm also happy to make the tag wiki for it, once created, whatever it ends up being.

Comment: On the plus side, at least the full title is not sitting at a tantalizing 26-characters of length.

Comment: In a similar vein, will Season 2 of the Telltale game remain tagged as [the-walking-dead]?

Comment: @MBraedley - As it's just DLC and nothing game-changing has been introduced (other than story), I think so. We did the same with SC2:Heart of the Swarm IIRC

Comment: @Robotnik I wouldn't really call it DLC. It's more of a sequel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a tentative Google search, I have discovered that [twd-survival-instinct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twd-survival-instinct) would give us the "Google juice" that we need. So I'd suggest that.

Answer (score 2):

**The tag name is now [the-walking-dead-survival-instinct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-survival-instinct).**

Since the tag length was [increased to 35 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've went ahead and [retagged your question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/146811/revisions) with the full title.